# why doesn't X change at 11th line of code? any advice

Tags: java, arrays

The problematic line is the one with the comment `x doesn't change`. The expected outcome is to print all the possible cards of a deck.

```
public class deal {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        String[] numbers ={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};
        String[] color = {"Hearts","Spades","Diamonds","Clubs"};

        String[] deck =new String[color.length * numbers.length];
        for(int x =0;x<color.length;x++)
            for(int y=0;y<numbers.length;y++) {
                deck[numbers.length*x+y] = numbers[y]+ " of " + color[x];//X doesn't change
                System.out.println(deck[y]);
            }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why should `x` change ? There is no assignment to it. (But it should increase each time the inner loop is completed, i.e. every 14 iterations)

Comment: same value of `x` will remain for every `y` loops in inner loop

Comment: X doesn't change until inner `for loop` complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` is changing. You are just printing the wrong array element. Try that:

```
System.out.println(deck[numbers.length*x+y]);
```

Alternative you can later print the array like that:

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length * color.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(deck[i]);
}
```

Or of course you can just do `i < 56`.

Answer (score 0):

In nested loops, value of external loop counter remain unchanged for all interations of the inner loop.
So for `x = 0` `Y` change from `0` to `numbers.lenght`. Then `x = 1` and so on.